# gluUnProject() giving incorrect values on mac(retina display) but works correctly on other systems

Tags: macos, opengl

The values returned by `gluUnProject()` are coming half of what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Retina display has DPI scaling, so the frame buffer size and the screen size do not match.

The fix is simply multiplying the screen coordinates with the devicePixelRatio which can be calculated as follows

```
const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

devicePixelRatio = bufferWidth / WIDTH;
```

Then you can calculate world coordinates with the following snippet of code.

```
void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos) {

  xpos *= devicePixelRatio;
  ypos *= devicePixelRatio;

  GLint viewport[4];
  GLdouble modelview[16];
  GLdouble projection[16];
  GLfloat winX, winY, winZ = 0;
  GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

  glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
  glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

  winX = (float)xpos;
  winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)ypos;
  glReadPixels(xpos, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

  gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY,
               &posZ);

  cout<<posx<<posy<<posz<<endl;
}
```